# How can I create an object that recieves Gson().fromJson()

Tags: java, json, rest, gson

I am trying to consume a rest API called kolada. The problem I´m having is that when I try to consume the web service it doesn´t work. I have looked everywhere and tried creating objects that work for the correct Json format but I can´t figure it out. It isn´t actually returning an error it is just returning null.

Here is the url I´m trying to reach:
http://api.kolada.se/v2/municipality?title=lund

Here is the Object_structure for the api

```
{
    "id": "<string>",
    "title": "<string>",
    "type": "L|K"
}
```

This is the object I´ve created

```
public class search_string {
    String id;
    String title;
    String type;


    public String get_the_shit()
    {

    return id+title+type;      
    }    
}
```

This is when I´m trying to call it (I´m calling it from a gui/Jframe event)

```
try {


            String url ="http://api.kolada.se/v2/municipality?title=lund";

            InputStreamReader a = new InputStreamReader(new URL(url).openStream());

            search_string b = new Gson().fromJson(a, search_string.class);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, b.toString());


        } 

        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WelcomeRESTXMLClientJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

But it returns an empty string.

I have no idea what I´m doing wrong. I suspect it is my object class.

Can anyone help or give suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You need the container class, and you must define getters and setters methods

```
{
  "count": 1,
  "values": [
    {
      "id": "1281",
      "title": "Lund",
      "type": "K"
    }
  ]
}
```

the correct class to map this json is

```
public class MyClass {
    private int count;
    private List<MyOtherClass> values;

    get*()
    set(*)
}

public class MyOtherClass {

    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String type;

    get*()
    set(*)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The structure of JSON returned by that URL is different. I got the following:

```
{"count": 1, "values": [{"id": "1281", "title": "Lund", "type": "K"}]}
```

So your `search_string` should be mapped to a collection element, not the whole object.

Try adding the following wrapper

```
public class Envelope {
    private List<search_string> strings = new ArrayList();
    ...
}
```

and deserialize using `Envelope.class` and not `search_string.class`.